# What is wrong with build.gradle? Getting UnsatisfiedLinkError because it's missing my so file

Tags: gradle, android-ndk, build.gradle

I upgraded the project to `com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-beta5`

and did everything described in http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

HOWEVER, upon running the app there's an exception:

```
02-23 23:45:56.731 30326-30326/my.android.project I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-23 23:45:57.056 30326-30326/my.android.project D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-23 23:45:57.059 30326-30326/my.android.project E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: my.android.project, PID: 30326
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/my.android.project-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/my.android.project-2/lib/arm64, /data/app/my.android.project-2/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjni-utils.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
    at my.android.project.JNIutils.<clinit>(JNIutils.java:10)
    at my.android.project.ApplicationContext.onCreate(ApplicationContext.java:66)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**The Project's Build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-beta5"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                shrinkResources false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
                signingConfig = $("android.signingConfigs.release")
            }
        }

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "my.android.project"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 16
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 214
            versionName "2alpha14"
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "native"
            ldLibs.add("log")
            cppFlags.add("-std=c++11")
            cppFlags.add("-fexceptions")
            stl "gnustl_shared"
        }
    }

    android.signingConfigs {
        create("release") {
            storeFile "C:\\Android\\Git\\project\\keystore\\keystoreTTC"
            storePassword "[CENSORED]"
            keyAlias "[CENSORED]"
            keyPassword "[CENSORED]"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
}
```

**local.properties**

```
## This file is automatically generated by Android Studio.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must *NOT* be checked into Version Control Systems,
# as it contains information specific to your local configuration.
#
# Location of the SDK. This is only used by Gradle.
# For customization when using a Version Control System, please read the
# header note.
#Mon Jan 04 15:04:21 CET 2016
ndk.dir=C\:\\Android\\sdk\\ndk-bundle
sdk.dir=C\:\\Android\\sdk
```

**and gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Sun Feb 07 11:11:15 GMT 2016
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

There's no errors in the build process.

What is going wrong ?

**Note**
the .c file is located in its default location at
`\project\app\src\main\jni\jni-utils.c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app is trying to load *libjni-utils.so*, but your module is named *native*, instead of *jni-utils*.

Inside your *build.gradle* file, change this line:

```
moduleName "native"
```

to

```
moduleName "jni-utils"
```